# How to save files using correct Design Pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I've done my due diligence and searched for a while now but I don't understand enough about design patterns to find a useful example. How would file-uploads factor into Design Patterns? Should these be included within the Repository Pattern?

So my question is two-fold:

- Should file-uploads get included into the objects being passed into
  the repository and then saved there?
- Or should a separate object handle this using an other specific Pattern?

A simple example would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about an uploaded file in a controller, you could do something like the following:

**Controller:**

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly IFileRepository _fileRepository;

    //Wire up the IFileRepository injection via IoC container (Ninject, StructureMap, etc.)
    public MyController(IFileRepository fileRepository)
    {
        _fileRepository = fileRepository;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase file) //assuming you're just posting a file
    {
        //note: instead of HttpPostedFileBase you could iterate through
        //      Request.Files
        if(file == null)
        {
            //do something here b/c the file wasn't posted...
        }

        try
        {
            _fileRepository.Save(file);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //log exception...display friendly message to user, etc...
        }

        return View("MyView");

    }

}
```

**IFileRepository**

```
public interface IFileRepository
{
    void SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase file);
}

//concrete implementation
public class FileRepository : IFileRepository
{
    public void SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //your file saving logic, ie. file.SaveAs(), etc...
    }
}
```

The advantage of injecting the interface is that it allows for easier Unit Testing and also allows for different implementations of IFileRepository.  You may have a file repository that acts differently for different environments, etc.

Comment: Maybe your IFileRepository for local and development persists to the local file system but the one for QA and production save to amazon S3, or something.

Comment: Ok!  I see!  So then I don't include this logic into per say the ProductRepository? What i'm doing is basically creating a Product Knowledgebase and it includes attachments.  I'm just not sure where to stick the attachment saving logic...  I don't want to clutter up the Productrepository unnecessarily.

Comment: You probably need some sort of service to handle this.  IProductKnowledgeBaseService or something that fits your domain language.  In that, you could inject your ProductRepository and file repository and then handle the the transaction between the two.

Answer (score 0):

> Should file-uploads get included into the objects being passed into
>   the repository and then saved there?

Yes, when you persist the uploaded file, you can use a repository.

For example

```
var repository = GetRepository();
repository.SaveFile(File file);
```

> Or should a separate object handle this using a Factory Pattern?

No, Factory pattern is for creating instances of objects.